# Wyvern and CKEDITOR

Tags: channel, fields, rte, wyvern, ckeditor

We're trying to get Wyvern/CKEDITOR to show up on our dashboard that we created. It shows up beautiful in the control panel, just not the dashboard. We've been scouring the web for clues or hints of code to point us in the right direction. When ee-rte is selected, it works beautifully on the dashboard. Just not Wyvern!

I've tried {field:mission} (thanks to Brian Litzinger) which got us some what closer. But we're stuck yet again. Posted below is a picture of what is happening.

[image: Picture of Dashboard.]

And here is the code:

```
  <div class="form-element-wrapper" id="mission-container">
    <label for="mission">Mission</label>
      <textarea name="fife" id="fife" rows="12" styles="width:100%;">
        {field:mission}
      </textarea>
  </div>
```

I've linked the ckeditor.js. I've even tried CKEDITOR.replace (which is why the id and class say 'fife' still). I've done about almost every combination my brain can think of. What are we missing? Any help or suggestions will be extremely helpful! Thank you everyone for your time.

**EDIT 1:** {field:mission} *does* render textarea in *source*, just does *not* display. Here is what we see.

```
<textarea style="margin-top: 30px; height: 200px; visibility: hidden;" class="wyvern" id="mission" name="mission">mission text here</textarea>
```

**EDIT 2:** We figured it out: It was an issue with how we had the segments set up. Once we changed everything to a more simpler segment layout, it worked perfectly. {field:mission} DOES properly render the textarea and DOES display the editor beautifully now on the front end. Thanks for the help, Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just:

```
 <div class="form-element-wrapper" id="mission-container">
    <label for="mission">Mission</label>
    {field:mission}
  </div>
```

{field:mission} will render the textarea for you.

Comment: Hey Brian. I have tried just that, and noticed it does render the textarea for us. However, it still does not show up. Here is what we're seeing in the source. <textarea style="margin-top: 30px; height: 200px; visibility: hidden;" class="wyvern" id="mission" name="mission">mission text here</textarea>

Comment: We figured it out: It was an issue with how we had the segments set up.